# Is there a possibility to send open door event and read password from ZKteco RS485 rfid connected with C3-400

Tags: c#, sdk, access-control, rfid, zkteco

I am trying to write a customized program in C# to use ZKteco RFID and key password to create an access control system. simply I need to do two things:

1- Read RFID card or a password from the c3-400 (which is connected to RS485 reader).

2- Send a signal to open or close a control access door connected to c3-400.

the problem is that the device is connected but not neither the card nor the key password triggering any event.

I used their SDK but none of the events triggered even after I checked that I activate all events using RegEvent function (mentioned in Zkteco SDK). I contacted their support team but they didn't reply.

this is the code I use to register all realtime events

```cs
if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(GetMachineNumber(), 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
            {
                //common interface
                this.axCZKEM1.OnFinger += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFinger);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnFingerFeature += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerFeatureEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnFingerFeature);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnDeleteTemplate += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDeleteTemplateEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDeleteTemplate);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnNewUser += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnNewUserEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnNewUser);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnHIDNum += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnHIDNumEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnHIDNum);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnAlarm += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAlarmEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAlarm);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnDoor += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDoorEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnDoor);

                //only for color device
                this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnEnrollFingerEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEnrollFingerEx);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnGeneralEvent += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnGeneralEventEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnGeneralEvent);

                //only for black&white device
                this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransaction -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransaction);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnWriteCard += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnWriteCardEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnWriteCard);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnEmptyCard += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEmptyCardEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEmptyCard);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnKeyPress += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnKeyPressEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnKeyPress);
                this.axCZKEM1.OnEnrollFinger += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnEnrollFinger);


                ret = 1;
            }
```

I even put breakpoints in each event function but none of the events triggered when I pass the card or press the key ( although the device is working with red light and sounds so it is connected correctly).
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so, could you post your solution?

Comment: @Poosh No, I couldn't and had to change the Zkteco system

Answer (score 0):

You need [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to listen to the C3-400 and then open ZKAcess 3.5, click monitor and there is connection key sent by ZKAcess to the C3-400.

If an RFID is received, you can parse it.

If your problem still exists, tell me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, I am no longer working on this project, as you can see it was 7 months ago. but I hope someone will find your answer useful
Note: I couldn't find the solution back then